# Multiple Select Strings in a for loop to separate files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I wrote this script to search a lot of text files (~100,000) for 4 different search criteria and export to 4 separate files, I thought it would be more efficient to perform all 4 searches on each file as it is loaded vs doing 4 full searches like the first iteration below does. I may be missing some other major inefficiencies as I am pretty new to powershell.

I have this script re written from the first version to the second, but can't figure out how to get the path and data to display together like the first version did. I am struggling to reference the object within the loop, and have pieced this second version together, which is working, but not giving me the path to the file which is necessary.

It seems like I am just missing one or two little things to get me going in the right direction. Thanks in advance for your help

1st version:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path "\\file\to\search" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "abc123" -Context 0,3 | Out-File -FilePath "\\c:\out.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path "\\file\to\search2" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "abc124" -Context 0,3 | Out-File -FilePath "\\c:\out2.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path "\\file\to\search3" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "abc125" -Context 0,3 | Out-File -FilePath "\\c:\out3.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path "\\file\to\search4" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "abc126" -Context 0,3 | Out-File -FilePath "\\c:\out4.txt"
```

Output:

```
  \\file\that\was\found\example.txt:84:  abc123  
  \\file\that\was\found\example.txt:90:  abc123 
  \\file\that\was\found\example.txt:91:  abc123
```

2nd version:

```
##$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Configuration $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

############################################ Global Parameters #############################################
$SearchPath="\\file\to\search"
$ProgressFile=""\\progress\file\ResultsCount.txt"
$records = 105325
##----------------------------------------- End Global Parameters -----------------------------------------

########################################### Search Parameters ##############################################
##Search Pattern 1
$Pattern1="abc123"
$SaveFile1="\\c:\out.txt"

##Search Pattern 2
$Pattern2="abc124"
$SaveFile2="\\c:\out2.txt"

##Search Pattern 3
$Pattern3= "abc125" 
$SaveFile3= "\\c:\out3.txt"

##Search Pattern 4
$Pattern4= "abc126"
$SaveFile4="\\c:\out4.txt"
 
##Search Pattern 5
$Pattern5= ""
$SaveFile5=""

##----------------------------------------- End Search Parameters ------------------------------------------
##$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ End of Config $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

############################### SCRIPT #####################################################################
                                                                                                          ## NOTES
                                                                                                          ## ------
##$files=Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path $SearchPath -Recurse                                             ## Set all files to variable ####  Long running, needs to be a better way #######
##$records=$files.count                                                                                     ## Set record #
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Path $SearchPath -Recurse | Foreach-Object {                                 ## loop through search folder
$i=$i+1                                                                                                   ## increment record
                                                                                                          ##
Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern1 -Context 0,3 | Out-File -FilePath $SaveFile1   ## pattern1 search
Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern2 | Out-File -FilePath $SaveFile2                ## pattern2 search
Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern3 -Context 0,1 | Out-File -FilePath $SaveFile3   ## pattern3 search
Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern4 -Context 0,1 | Out-File -FilePath $SaveFile4   ## pattern4 search
##Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern5 -Context 0,1 | Out-File -FilePath $SaveFile5 ## pattern5  search (Comment out unneeded search lines like this one)
$progress ="Record $($i) of $($records)"                                                                  ## set progress
Write-Host "Record $($i) of $($records)"                                                                  ## Writes progress to window
$progress  | Out-File -FilePath $ProgressFile                                                             ## progress file
}                                                                                                         ##
############################################################################################################
```

Output:

```
abc123
abc123
abc123
```

Edit: Also I am trying to figure out a good way to not have to hard code in the number of records for a decent progress readout, I commented out the way I thought would work (1st & 2nd line of the script), but there needs to be a more efficient way than rerunning the same search twice, one for a count and one for the for loop.

I would be very interested in any runtime efficiency information you could provide.

Comment: `-Pattern` is regex compatible, you can do it on one go joining the words with `|`. Also note, on your second example, the files are being overwritten due to `-Append` not being there.

Comment: Wouldn't that write them all to the same outfile though? Thanks for the -append tip!

Comment: Your first example is fine because all files are being processed on the same pipeline (`Get-Content (all txt files)` > `Select-String (reads them all and outputs all findings)` > `Out-File (captures all outputs from Select-String and saves them on a file)`) on the second example however, there is an outer loop hence on each iteration whenever there is a finding the file is being effectively replaced. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That definitely does make sense, also why I can't get a good count, since its only passing one record at a time. I am still confused on why the way I built the second time is changing the output to not show me the file path.

Comment: @Ryan, it is because you are piping object from Get-ChildItem to Select-String in the first example, and piping object from Get-Content to Select-String in second. In the second example, you are piping a string.

Comment: @dugas, This was the only way I could get it to function, is there a better way to reference the object? TBH, I found that on someone else's script.

Comment: You can use Get-Item instead of Get-Content to get same output you got in first example. As @SantiagoSquarzon mentioned though, you need to append with Out-File, or it is going to get overwritten.

Comment: Ok the picture is coming together a bit. the script is now fully functional with those two changes. Any tips on getting a file count without setting all items to a variable and doing a count of the variable? That works, but has to pull in the 100K+ items twice, and it could be 10 times larger next time.

Comment: Thank you SantiagoSquarzon & @dugas for the help, I appreciate you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take at solving this problem, very similar to [Lee_Dailey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456333/15339544) nice answer but with a `foreach` loop. I would recommend investing some time into researching the multi-threading options available on PowerShell in case you need to increase the performance of the script, you can look specifically at the [ThreadJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.2) module by Microsoft which is really easy to use or if you can't install modules due to some work policy, you can use [Runspace](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/).

It is worth adding that you can use the `-List` switch on [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2), this way the performance of the script would be increased even more:

> `-List`
> Only the first instance of matching text is returned from each input file. This is the most efficient way to retrieve a list of files that have contents matching the regular expression.

```
$map = @{
    abc123 = 'C:\out_abc123.txt'
    abc124 = 'C:\out_abc124.txt'
    abc125 = 'C:\out_abc125.txt'
}

$pattern = $map.Keys -join '|'

$match = foreach($file in Get-ChildItem *.txt)
{
    Select-String -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Pattern $pattern
}

$match | Group-Object { $_.Matches.Value } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Select-Object Path, LineNumber, Line | Out-File $map[$_.Name]
}
```

Comment: Both Answers are very helpful , and both get my upvote and further research into how they work, but Santiago helped me get my script to be functional first before he posted his thoughtful follow-up answer, so I have to give him the credit.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan, both answers are equally valid, if you are thinking about giving multithreading a chance start with some code and post again if you're stuck for sure I'll help you if I see the question :)

Answer (score 3):

[edit - thanks to mklement0 for pointing out the errors about speed and the `-SimpleMatch` switch. [*grin*]]

the `Select-String` cmdlet will accept a `-Path` parameter ... and it is <strike>FAR</strike> [i was thinking of `Get-Content`, not `Get-ChidItem`] faster than using `Get-ChildItem` to feed the files to `S-S`. [*grin*]

also, the `-Pattern` parameter accepts a regex `OR` pattern like `Thing|OtherThing|YetAnotherThing` - and it accepts simple string patterns if you use the `-SimpleMatch` switch parameter.

what the code does ...

- defines the source dir
- defines the file spec
- joins those two into a wildcard file path
- builds an array of string patterns to use
- calls `Select-String` with a path and an array of strings to search for
- uses `Group-Object` and a calculated property to group the matches by the last part of `.Line` property from the `S-S` call
- saves that to a $Var
- shows that on screen

at that point, you can use the `.Name` property of each `GroupInfo` to select the items to send out to each file AND to build your file names.

the code ...

```
$SourceDir = 'D:\Temp\zzz - Copy'
$FileSpec = '*.log'
$SD_FileSpec = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $FileSpec

$TargetPatternList = @(
    'Accordion Cajun Zydeco'
    'better-not-be-there'
    'Piano Rockabilly Rowdy'
    )

$GO_Results = Select-String -Path $SD_FileSpec -SimpleMatch $TargetPatternList |
    Group-Object -Property {$_.Line.Split(':')[-1]}

$GO_Results
```

output ...

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                     
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                     
    6 Accordion Cajun Zydeco    {D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-02.log:11:Accordion Cajun Zydeco, D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-09.log:11:Accordion Cajun Zy...
    6 Bawdy Dupe Piano Rocka... {D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-02.log:108:Bawdy Dupe Piano Rockabilly Rowdy, D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-09.log:108:Bawdy...
    6 Bawdy Piano Rockabilly... {D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-02.log:138:Bawdy Piano Rockabilly Rowdy, D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-09.log:138:Bawdy Pian...
    6 Dupe Piano Rockabilly ... {D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-02.log:948:Dupe Piano Rockabilly Rowdy, D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-09.log:948:Dupe Piano ...
    6 Instrumental Piano Roc... {D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-02.log:1563:Instrumental Piano Rockabilly Rowdy, D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-09.log:1563:I...
    6 Piano Rockabilly Rowdy    {D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-02.log:1781:Piano Rockabilly Rowdy, D:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Grouping-List_08-09.log:1781:Piano Rockabil...
```

note that the `.Group` contains an array of lines from the matches sent out by the `S-S` call. you can send that to your output file.

Answer (score 0):

To compliment the answers [@Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) and [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey), I think you were actually on the good way yourself knowing that the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet is pretty expensive especially in memory usage as it chokes the PowerShell [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) causing all the search results to be piled up in memory.

Besides, the [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet supports multiple (`-SimpleMatch`) patterns, where concatenating the search patters with an `|` (`-join '|'`) will force you to use an (escaped) [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

To continue on your approach:
<sup>(note that in the example, I am using my own settings to search through my script files)</sup>

```
$ProgressFile = '.\ResultsCount.txt'
$SearchRoot = '..\'
$Filter = '*.ps1'
$Searches = @{
    'Null'   = '.\Null.txt'
    'Test'   = '.\Test.txt'
    'Object' = '.\Object.txt'
}

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Filter $Filter -Path $SearchRoot -Recurse
$Total = $Files.count

$Searches.Values |ForEach-Object { Set-Content -LiteralPath $_ -Value '' }

$i = 0
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    Get-Content -LiteralPath $File.FullName |
        Select-String @($Searches.Keys) -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {
            $Value = '{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $File.FullName, $_.LineNumber, $_
            Add-Content -LiteralPath $Searches[$_.Pattern] -Value $Value
        }
    'Record {0} of {1}' -f ++$i, $Total |Tee-Object -Append .\ProgressFile.txt
}
```

#### Explanations

- `$Searches = @{ ...`
  Maps the search patters with the files, you might also use a `PSObject` list to specify each search (where you could add columns with e.g. context start/end values, etc.)
- `$Searches.Values |ForEach-Object { Set-Content -LiteralPath $_ -Value '' }`
  Empties the result files (knowing that they are not part of the main stream you can't use `Add-Content`)
- `$i = 0`
  Unfortunately there is no automatic index that initializes with a `foreach` loop (yet, see: [`#13772` Automatic variable for the pipeline index](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772))
- `Get-Content -LiteralPath $File.FullName`
  Load the content once into memory
  **Note1:** this is a string *array*.
  **Note2:** the `$Content` will be reused each iteration and therefore overwrites the previous one and unloads it from memory
- `Select-String @($Searches.Keys) -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {`
  Searches the string array using your (multiple) defined patterns. (you might consider to use the `-SimpleMatch` parameter if your search strings contain special characters.)
  **Note:** Unfortunately you need to embedded the `$Searches.Keys` in a [array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--), for details see .Net issue: [`#56835` Make OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection implement IList](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56835)
- `$Value = '{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $File.FullName, $_.LineNumber, $_`
  Build an result output string.
  **Note:** the result of the `Select-String` does have a (hidden) `LineNumber` and (matched) `Pattern` property.
- `Add-Content -LiteralPath $Searches[$_.Pattern] -Value $Value`
  Add the result string to the specific mapped output file.
- `'Record {0} of {1}' -f $i++, $Total |Tee-Object -Append .\ProgressFile.txt`
  [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) will write the progress to the standard output (display) and also to the specific file.

Comment: I have updated my answer as I forgot about the fact that `Select-String` supports multiple patterns which is another argument to go for your original approach.